# Angular Material mat-chip validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I validate if the user has selected a `chip` in the `mat-chip-list` and also only when the user selects a `chip` form should become valid. Right now I have the `validators.required` set on the control, but it doesn't work.
This is what I have done so far:

---

HTML

```
<mat-chip-list formControlName="packageName">
   <mat-chip *ngFor="let pkg of packages" selected="true" style="background-color:#8d6e63">
        {{pkg.value}}
   </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

---

TS

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    'packageName': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `form.status` to get the form status VALID or INVALID or `form.controls.packageName.errors` to get an array of the formControl errors or null if no errors.

[Here is a running example using your code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49959928)

Comment: Thanks ibenjelloun, that worked like a charm. Have been struggling with this for almost couple days now. Didn't know it was this easy. Working example provided helped a lot. Thanks for putting that together for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```js
... (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, postForm.get('tags'))" />
```

```js
export interface Tag {
  name: string;
}
...

tags: Tag[] = [];
...

add(event: MatChipInputEvent, form: AbstractControl | null): any {
  // add tag from keyboard
  const input = event.chipInput;
  const value = event.value;
  // Reset the input value
  if (input) {
    input.clear();
  }
  // Add tag
  if ((value || '').trim()) {
    this.tags.push({ name: tag.trim() });
  }

  // set value for validation  <--- key code here
  form?.setValue(this.tags);

  return this.tags;
}
```

The key here is adding a blank value or an empty value to the actual form control.

**UPDATE:** - I also found another version using [form groups](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-gywxjz?file=app%2Fchip-list-validation-example.ts).